# Caching User Data with multi-tennancy

Tags: c#, caching, .net-core

I'm trying to understand how to cache better.  Let's say I have a controller which returns data specific to a organizations

I have a context using mutlti-tenancy,

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employees>().Property<string> ("TenantId").HasField("_tenantId");

    // Configure entity filters
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employees>().HasQueryFilter(b => EF.Property<string>(b, "TenantId") == _tenantId);
}
```

and some method to return the employees in an organization

```
public Employee[] GetEmployees(int organizationId)
{
    var employees = this._context.Employees.Where(x => x.OrganizationId == organizationId).ToArray();
    return employees;
}
```

If I were to cache this it might look something like:

```
public Employee[] GetEmployees(int organizationId)
{
    if(this.TryGetFromCache(organizationId, out var cachedEmployees)
    {
        return cachedEmployees;
    } 

    var employees = this._context.Employees.Where(x => x.OrganizationId == organizationId).ToArray();

    this.AddToCache(organizationId, employees);
    return employees;
}
```

My issue is how do I verify that the user requesting the employees has access to cached employees?

Comment: I'm assuming the user is already authenticated with OAuth or a JWT token or equivalent, and you already have their 'orginizationId' so I don't understand your final question? Why wouldn't they have access, what do you need to verify beyond authenticating them? (On a side note, take an up vote because Short Circuit is an epic film.)

Comment: Another way of looking at it - how would this question be different if you weren't caching?

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt a user may be authenticated to the system but that doesnt mean they're authorized to obtain the entities.  e.g they maybe able to view the employess of the organization tree theyre in e.g parent and child organizations but Not employees of a separate company

Comment: @ScottHannen If i wasn't caching this would automatically be handled by the filter in the DbContext.  But since im caching perhaps the user may have access to the employees in there company tree e.g parent and children but not have access to the employees in a separate entity completely

Comment: The authorization should be implemented at a higher level like the controller, not just within EF, for exactly this reason. I was going to say, "What will happen if you want to return this data some other way besides EF - you'd have to find another way to implement authorization?" Then I realized that's exactly where you're already at. Regardless of the EF filter, a request from a user who isn't authorized shouldn't even get that far.

Comment: @ScottHannen They're authorized to use that controller, they're just not authorized to access the data.   There is no way to authorize before hand for every controller generically there could be complex filters, most of them which can only be resolved with a dbContext.

Comment: @johnny5 ok cool thanks, so what you're looking for is a way to implement roles, to determine who has rights access to cached entities.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt no I dont think roles fits the description of tenancy, e.g administrator, and customer would be considered a role,  your roles shouldn't be reliant on your db, under that definition if a new company was created you would need to create a new role

Comment: @johnny5 honestly that's semantics. Permission and access should be determined at a higher level for both your controllers and data-sources respectively. I'm not suggesting they be reliant on your DB, I'm suggesting they are reliant on something like roles or groups within AAD for example; or whatever other mechanism you use for authorisation / user validation.

Comment: I think first you need to figure out our authentication problem which is happening at lower level of the application ... you need to do something about it. as the other comments are suggesting try to separate it from the reading an Org, you can make a service separately to make the authentication and you can call it in the controller. you are able to cache that one as well if you are worried about performance.